Adaptive grid for 1D complex function.
TLDR: Where can I read about 1D adaptive mesh algorithms?
I work on optical system modeling. I have a complex function $y=f(x)$ that I want to calculate at every point in range $[x_{min}, x_{max}]$. What do we know about this function:

It's smooth and will never reach infinity
It's highly nonlinear, both in magnitude and phase
It most probably has rapid oscillations (large group delay)
It might have many resonances, where magnitude and phase change rapidly
It can be computed at every point $x$, but it's computationally demanding.

I'm working on adaptive algorithm that would calculate f(x) at certain points, so that I could interpolate in between. And I somehow can't find any literature on the topic. I've managed to find 'python-adaptive' library, but it refines places that shouldn't be refined and vice versa. All the literature I've found talks about 2D and 3D adaptive mesh refinement. Everyone is omitting 1D case with "it's simple and obvious".
So my question is - what is the algorithm for 1D adaptive grid? Where can I read more about it? Someone HAD to do this already.
